# The name 'listener' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

This is my first time posting here, and I'm relatively new to programming, so apologies if this is a bit of a dumb question.

Basically, I'm creating fairly simple asynchronous server and client applications in C#. However, as you can see from the below code, I'm being told "the name 'listener' does not exist in the current context."

I've attempted changing private to public, but that makes no difference. I'm sure it's a pretty obvious issue, but if someone could point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Async_Chat_Server
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Socket socket;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        }
        private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Listen for input coming from any IP address on specified port
                int port = int.Parse(PortTextBox.Text);
                TcpListener listener;
                listener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, port);
                listener.Start();
                // Create an event handler for dealing with incoming connections
                listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(
                new AsyncCallback(AcceptIncomingConnection), listener);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Update display to show error message
                DisplayTextBox.Text = "Socket connection error:\n" + ex.ToString();
            }
        }
        private void AcceptIncomingConnection(IAsyncResult incomingConnection) // CALLBACK
        {
            // Accept incoming socket connection
            socket = listener.EndAcceptSocket(incomingConnection);
            // Set up an event handler for receiving messages
            Receive();
        }
        private void StopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            socket.Close();
            listener.Stop();
        }
        private void SendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Prepare message
            byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(MessageTextBox.Text);
            // Send it
            socket.BeginSend(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(TransmitHandler), socket);
        }
        private void TransmitHandler(IAsyncResult info) // CALLBACK
        {
            int bytesSent = socket.EndSend(info);
        }
        private void Receive()
        {
            socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None,
            ReceiveHandler, socket);
        }
        private void ReceiveHandler(IAsyncResult messageInfo) // CALLBACK
        {
            // Read message
            int numBytesReceived = socket.EndReceive(messageInfo);
            string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, numBytesReceived);
            // Update display
            DisplayTextBox.Text = message;
            // Reset the event handler for new incoming messages
            Receive();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 TcpListener listener;
```

move this line outside of the method.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Socket socket;
    TcpListener listener;
    ...
}
```